# How can I prevent the patch command from exiting a bash shell?

Tags: bash, patch

I have a bash script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

function patchStuff {
  patch --unified --input=<...>.patch --strip=0 --forward --reject-file=<...>.patch.rej --verbose --dry-run
}

function doMoreThings {}

patchStuff
doMoreThings # never reached

exit 0
```

It completes/exits right after the `patch` command completes. How can I prevent, stop or ignore that. I played with running the command in a subshell, but that didn't do the trick.

> bash -c "patch ..."

Comment: `patch` must be reporting an error, and `set -e` means you want the script to exit when any command gets an error. Don't use that option if you don't want it.

Comment: Don't use `set -e`; do your own error checking and exit when *you* decide it is appropriate.

Comment: Of course, my mind wasn't going there because the output didn't show any errors and the last logged line was `done`. Something must have been logging stuff to stderr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want a particular command to trigger the exit that `set -e` specifies, you can negate it.

```
! patch ...
```

POSIX and the `bash` manual specify that `set -e` doesn't apply to a command that has been negated with `!`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of negating you also can always return 0 exit status:

```
patch ... ||:
```

or

```
patch ... || true
```